# How to rename properties of objects in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript objects:

```
var arr = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}]
```

I need to rename properties with `name` in arr1 to `title`:

```
var arr = [{id:'124',title:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',title:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',title:'eee'},
           {id:'567',title:'rrr'}]
```

What is elegant way to implement it in Javascript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `delete` to remove a property from an object.
Use `obj['newProperty']` to assign `newProperty` to an object.

```js
var arr = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}];
           
arr.forEach( function(data) {
  data['title'] = data['name'];
  delete data['name'];
});

console.log(arr);
```

You can also use `array#map`

```js
const arr = [{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '45', name: 'eee' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' } ],
      result = arr.map(({name, ...rest}) => ({...rest, title: name}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) :

```js
var arr = [{
    id: '124',
    name: 'qqq'
  },
  {
    id: '589',
    name: 'www'
  },
  {
    id: '45',
    name: 'eee'
  },
  {
    id: '567',
    name: 'rrr'
  }
]

arr = arr.map((e) => {
  return {
    id: e.id,
    title: e.name
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: can I use map method in every browser?

Comment: @Michael Did you follow my link ?

Comment: @Michael yes... ie9+

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.map(e => { return { id: e.id, title: e.name }});
```

Comment: I'd recommen to add some comment to your answer. Without it, it may be not obvious that, for instance, if some object has an extra property (say, "date"), your solution will cause its "deletion" in the array.

Comment: @MarceloGondim map does not modify the original array, you either have to reassign arr to the result of this, or you have to assign it to a new variable.

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible to change the name of property, but add a new one and delete the old one, i also got the code from somewhere dont remeber the exact source

```
function changeKey(originalKey, newKey, arr)
{
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    var obj = arr[i];
    obj[newKey] = obj[originalKey];
    delete(obj[originalKey]);
    newArr.push(obj);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you delete key and value and assign to new key:

```js
var arr = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}]
           
arr.forEach(function(o) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, 'title',
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'name'));
    delete o['name'];
});           
console.log(arr);
```