# How to remap array in React

Tags: javascript

How to do a remapo for new objects like:

```
...
const inputArr = [
{id: '1', name: "test1", routeName: "somethig/something"},
{id: '2', name: "something2", routeName: "foo/bar"},
{id: '3', name: "someanothrelement", routeName: "test/test"}
]

//to => 

const resultStructureArr = [
  { id: '1', value: 'somethig/something', label: 'test1' },
  { id: '2', value: 'foo/bar', label: 'something2' },
  { id: '3', value: 'test/test', label: 'someanothrelement' },
];
...
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruce97q0/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `map()` can do it

```js
const inputArr = [
{id: '1', name: "test1", routeName: "somethig/something"},
{id: '2', name: "something2", routeName: "foo/bar"},
{id: '3', name: "someanothrelement", routeName: "test/test"}
]

let result = inputArr.map(a => ({'id':a.id,'label':a.name,'value':a.routeName}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You have enough rep to know that a question like this is undoubtedly a duplicate. vote to close.

Comment: @pilchard,You are right,but I am just want to make my reputation over 10000,thanks

Comment: That is the worst reason to answer duplicates.

Comment: @pilchard Ok,I got it and will avoid it,thanks again

Comment: by 'avoid it' you mean you will flag this question as duplicate and delete your answer?

Comment: @pilchard I voted to close it and I do not want to delete it,hmmm....

Comment: perhaps you can look at the identical answer in the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/44966776/13762301

Answer (score -1):

We can use traditional `for` loop for this. Where we may loop to the length of list and for each iteration we may add new object into result array using [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method. Secondly we are doing the same thing with foreach loop. Third I'm using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, Which creates a new result for each iteration, in our case we are returning our new object. Lastly we are using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method, with this method we can initialize a starting value which in my case I'm using empty array, then for each iteration I'm pushing a new object in that array and returning it.

```js
const inputArr = [
  { id: "1", name: "test1", routeName: "somethig/something" },
  { id: "2", name: "something2", routeName: "foo/bar" },
  { id: "3", name: "someanothrelement", routeName: "test/test" },
];

// Using for loop
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
  result.push({
    id: inputArr[i].id,
    value: inputArr[i].routeName,
    label: inputArr[i].name,
  });
}

console.log(result);

result = [];
// using foreach loop
inputArr.forEach((item) => {
  result.push({ id: item.id, label: item.name, value: item.routeName });
});

console.log(result);

result = [];
// using map
result = inputArr.map((item) => ({
  id: item.id,
  label: item.name,
  value: item.routeName,
}));

console.log(result);
result = [];
// using reduce
result = inputArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push({ id: curr.id, label: curr.name, value: curr.routeName });
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```